# Odoo-bin give Unexpected token "Scaffold" in expression or statement in PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, odoo, odoo-12

I just starting to learn Odoo, When I read about their docs they said there is a command called `odoo-bin`, but when I run the command in PowerShell, it gives me an error:

```
At line:1 char:54
+ ... python.exe' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin' scaffo ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin'' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:105
+ ... ' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin' scaffold custom_ ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'scaffold' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

What is that mean? what I missed? Below here is how I run the command:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin" scaffold custom_salesorder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons"
```

The `python.exe` location is right, the `odoo-bin` file exists in that folder, it still give me an error. I use odoo 12.

Comment: Have you created the Configuration file for odoo?

Comment: Try to add a single dot and space (`. `) before the command

Comment: @mhu The dot operator only works incidentally. The correct solution is to use the call operator (`&`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PowerShell echoes strings instead of executing them. You need the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) (`&`) to tell PowerShell to execute the given string as a command.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> "C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE"
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
PS C:\> "C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE" "127.0.0.1"
At line:1 char:32
+ "C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE" "127.0.0.1"
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '"127.0.0.1"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

PS C:\> & "C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE" "127.0.0.1"

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Change your commandline to this, and the problem will disappear:

```
& "c:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin" scaffold custom_salesorder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons"
```

Comment: thanks the "&" command should be written in odoo docs, thanks man, u saved my day